# Align divs while keeping the basic structure

Tags: html, css

This is my div structure

ONE //top level

TWO THREE // 2 divs side by side in middle level

FOUR //bottom level

```
<div id="ONE">
  <div></div>
  <div><img src="logo.png"></div>
</div>

<div id "FIVE">
  <div id="TWO">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="THREE">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="FOUR">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

My question: How do I align `TWO` to the bottom level of `THREE` while keeping the same top, middle and bottom div setup.

I tried adding position :relative; to "FIVE" and `position: absolute` to "TWO" and "THREE". But then "FIVE" was overlapping "ONE"

**EDIT:**
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3e69kz4/)

```
#ONE{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
#FIVE{
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #cdb79e;
    position:relative;
}
#TWO {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #9e0b0f;
    position:relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#THREE{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #088da5;
    position:relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: some visual representation or a fiddle will help everyone to understand issue quickly.

Comment: Please post the CSS you tried so far

Comment: You should play with `display: table` and `display: table-cell`.

Comment: @Thangadurai: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j3e69kz4/

Comment: @Salketer: Please see https://jsfiddle.net/j3e69kz4/

Answer (score 1):

See jsfiddle with `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;`

```
#FIVE{
    display: table;
    width: 100px;
}
#TWO {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #900;

    width: 50%;
    height: 10px;
}
#THREE{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #08a;

    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sw_double/pepjxL2c/

Answer (score -1):

Use float properties and apply proper css. See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3e69kz4/2) for more information.

Markup

```
<div id="ONE">
  <div style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red; width: 50%; float: left; height: 100%;">&nbsp; DIV 1</div>
  <div style="width: 50%; float: left; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% blue; height: 100%;">&nbsp; DIV 2</div>
</div>

<div id="FIVE">
  <div id="TWO">
    <div  style="width: 50%; float: left; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% green; height: 100%;">&nbsp; DIV 3</div>
    <div  style="width: 50%; float: left; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% yellow; height: 100%;">&nbsp; DIV 4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="THREE">
    <div style="width: 33.33%; float: left; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% red; height: 100%;">&nbsp; DIV 5</div>
    <div style="width: 33.33%; float: left; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% grey; height: 100%;">&nbsp; DIV 6</div>
    <div style="width: 33.33%; float: left; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% pink; height: 100%;">&nbsp; DIV 7</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="FOUR">
  <div>&nbsp; DIV 8</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#ONE{
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float:left;
}
#FIVE{
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #cdb79e;
    float:left;
}
#TWO {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #9e0b0f;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
#THREE{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #088da5;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
}
#FOUR{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: if you just wanted to place link ,you can very wall do that in a comment to question why to write a septate answer????